# Can there be multiple users of one Google Drive account?

Tags: google-drive-api

I have a web application that we are building.  We need a text editor to allow for our registered users to create and or edit documents.  We want the documents to be used within our app, but would like to use the Google drive interface to create/edit/upload docs.  What I am concerned about is the OAuth2 process.  I would like for our web app to be the authenticator, and allow our users access to our files/folders that are under our account rather than theirs.  Can we do this?  All of our users are authenticated by our application already, and we do not want them to have to use their personal credentials to access files used by our application.

Answer (score 0):

According to Google's documentation:

> Each Gmail account intended and designed for use by an individual
>   user. If you have multiple users frequently accessing the same account
>   from various locations, you may reach a Gmail threshold and your
>   account will be temporarily locked down.

Anecdotal evidence confirms this: a worker at a school [reported a 403 error](https://productforums.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/drive/RUunSecqvko) possibly caused by too many people logging into the same account at the same time.