# How to provide common storage for all app users?

Tags: android, google-drive-api, dropbox

I want to provide a common storage for the users of my Android application.

I have thought about Dropbox or Google drive, however at least Google drive seems to discourage simultaneous access to the same account from multiple/many devices, as discussed here:
[Can there be multiple users of one Google Drive account?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15395079/can-there-be-multiple-users-of-one-google-drive-account)
I am not sure if this is also a restriction with Dropbox.

The application is a space and gravity simulator, the idea is each user to be able to store hiss/hers favorite systems (which is already possible, but only offline on device only) and to make them available for other users (which is still pending).

This is the app: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rts.android.spacesim

It would be best, if the solution is 2.3+ compatible, since there still a lot of older devices out there.

However, my question is: what approach would you suggest me to use? Same storage, multiple (possibly simultaneously accessing it) users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What kind of application is it? Using the application account for all users of the app is absolutely the worst thing you can do over so many point of views I'm not even going to describe (unless the application is used just by you and a couple of friends that need to share some files, but then, just use Dropbox, no?).

Depending on the purpose of the application you could resort to a custom solution or try to use something that already exists. Both Dropbox (https://www.dropbox.com/developers) and Google Drive (https://developers.google.com/drive/) provide APIs for developers who want to use their services, and I'm sure there are better solutions using the API than just sharing the application account over thousands of users.

Without more details, however, it is diffucult to help you further!

Comment: Hi, the application is a space and gravity simulator, the idea is each user to be able to store hiss/hers favorite systems (which is already possible, offline on device only) and to make them available for other users (which is still pending).

This is the app: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rts.android.spacesim

Dropbox and Google drive are obvious choices, I do not know of they allow simultaneous access from many users on the same account (applications own account). And if it si possible to make own authorisation, without touching user's own dropbox or Google drive account

Comment: In this case I would go with a custom solution. Probably you can even store the data in a MySQL database without the trouble of managing the upload of files.

Comment: Sending files around is quite easy, they will be quite small and probably (not decided yet) - read only, at least for the non-authors.

What are the benefits of a custom solution over Dropbox or Google drive?

Comment: Since files are small and you don't need all the features of a real file hosting service I think using Dropbox or Drive would be an unnecessary overkill. Just encode the information in some way and save it in a MySQL table: much less to code and probably much more flexibility if you want to change/add features in the future.